# Wordpress comments box is not visible for recent posts

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a problem with the integration of the Facebook social plugin for Wordpress.
I activated the Facebook comments for my posts but this box only appears on just some posts.

For example:

- http://www.fredskitchen.fr/potatoes/ without comment box here
- http://www.fredskitchen.fr/margarita/ with comment box

I cannot understand why I have this strange behaviour. Everything else in the plugin works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Wordpress settings to ensure you have comments turned on by default.

/wp-admin/options-discussion.php

`[ ]` Allow people to post comments on new articles
<sub>(These settings may be overridden for individual articles.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, but this option is enabled and I still cannot see the comment box